# Testing for NIC card problems

Tags: linux, networking, network-adapter

I have two computers on the same LAN, on the same hub. When I run a speed test on one machine, I have 200mbps download speeds. The other computer gets 80mbps sometimes, sometimes 20mbps, and sometimes 1–3mbps. Both machines run Ubuntu.

I have tried running the problem computer from a live disk. I have tried a new modem, and new router. Here is what happens when I run `sudo ethtool -t eno1 online`:

```
The test result is PASS
The test extra info:
Register test  (offline)     0
Eeprom test    (offline)     0
Interrupt test (offline)     0
Loopback test  (offline)     0
Link test   (on/offline)     0
```

ifconfig:

```
RX packets 2395932  bytes 2467182203 (2.4 GB)
RX errors 0  dropped 12  overruns 0  frame 0
TX packets 1608399  bytes 805179437 (805.1 MB)
TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
device interrupt 20  memory 0xf7d00000-f7d20000
```

It seems to me that the problem has to be my hardware. Is it the motherboard? Is it the NIC card? I see some dropped packets, but I don't know how to diagnose further.

If it comes down to it, I will just buy a PCI NIC card and ignore the one that's integrated into the motherboard. However, I want to know in advance if this will solve the problem.

Comment: A cheap 1Gb NIC is €10 or some such, go get one... why bother with anything else?

Comment: Not a bad idea, to eliminate the NIC as the problem. But I wondered if there was a way to prove the NIC is the problem, and not, say, the motherboard.

Comment: OK, I bought a new NIC card and my connection was a lot better — for a few minutes. Now it's choppy and slow again. So I have replaced my modem, router and NIC card and I still have connectivity problems.

Comment: Grab the cable from the other computer (= known to be good) and try using it on the problem-computer.

Answer (score 1):

I had swapped out my cables, router, modem and NIC card. In the end, it was this: my cables weren't long enough, and I was using a coupler to join them together. Even when I changed both individual cables, the couple slowed me down. So there you go: a crummy coupler from the hardware store can dramatically reduce your network speed.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the article: [How to Troubleshoot Network Adapter Problems in Windows](https://community.fs.com/blog/troubleshoot-network-adapter-problems-in-windows.html) before. hope it can help you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).